# C# Read CSV to DataTable with comma inside CSV values

Tags: c#, visual-studio, csv, datatable, oledbconnection

I'm using OleDBConnection to read a CSV file and turn it into a DataTable. This is my function:

```
private DataTable csv2datatable(string caminho)
        {
            criarCsvSchema(caminho);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable("data");
            using (OleDbConnection conexao = new OleDbConnection(
                    "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
                    "Data Source=\"" + Path.GetDirectoryName(caminho) + "\";" +
                    "Extended Properties='text;HDR=yes;'"
                )
            )
            {
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(
                        string.Format("select * from [{0}]",new FileInfo(caminho).Name),
                        conexao
                    )
                )
                {
                    conexao.Open();
                    using(OleDbDataAdapter adaptador = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        adaptador.Fill(dt);
                    }
                }
            }
            return dt;
        }
```

The method "criarCsvSchema" creates the schema.ini with this configuration:

```
[CAM jan.csv]
ColNameHeader=True
Format=Delimited(;)
DecimalSymbol=,
```

My CSV file have this type of structure (It doesn't have quotes):

510,54;0,00;0,00;0,00;15,31;

So, the decimal symbol is ',' and the delimiter is ';'. When I run this project, I get this DataTable:

[image: output]

What I can't understand is: Why the first column "510,54" is correct and the others are returnerd as date?

**Thank you!**

@edit - the first 5 rows of the csv file (including the header):
https://github.com/rponciano/just-show/blob/master/shared-copy.csv

Comment: the values in other cols are dates arent they? what is the actual data which is being read as date and you think its not correct?l

Comment: @user1063108 All the values are money: Like U$0,00 or U$15,31.
Please, change the "down vote" if this was the reason.

Comment: I think if you could post sample content of the csv file it may help..I did not click on down vote

Comment: @user1063108 I edit the post with it

Comment: Try forcing the DateTimeFormat = YYYY-MM-DD in your schema.ini file. Strange.

Comment: LOL @RajN It work perfectly! Hahah I had not thought of that. Please, post so I can mark as Answer

Comment: Glad it worked. Good one though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @RajN commet, I just need force DateTimeFormat in the schema.ini.

"Try forcing the DateTimeFormat = YYYY-MM-DD in your schema.ini file."

Answer (score 0):

Your whole result is wierd. The cells "510,54" "0,00" "0,00" "0,00" and 15,31 are interpreted as: 1 Float and 4 datetimes?

My best guess is that the other values all evaluate to 30/12/1899 00:00, with the hours being truncated during output for being "propably irrelevant". So whatever you are doing wrong here, you are propably doing wrong with everything past the 1st value.

It is really hard to know without knowing the actuall values of the DataTable and how they are transformed before output as strings (wich code, wich culture). Something as simple as the display technology used might help, as each of the 5+ has a different DataTable.

Comment: Paragraph 1: Exactly!
Paragraph 2: I don't do anything. The whole process (for now) is the input of csv, turn it into datatable and show the datatable in datagridview.
Paragraph 3: How can I see this value before the output?

Comment: If all of those values are supposed to be currency, something goes either very wrong in the OleDB provider. Or the Datatables Display side. Looking into the values the Datatable has would help to nail it down. From there it is either the mapping to values in the Provider (another CSV read might allow you to define the types, if thise one does not) or a issue with the Display side (of wich you told us nothing).